# conncect QGIS to Postgis in a container return error message Failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "user"

Tags: java, docker-compose, postgis

I have a docker-compose.yml file with two image (Postgres extended PostGIS and pgadmin4) for a spring boot application:

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  postgis:
    image: postgis/postgis:15-3.3
    container_name: postgis_container
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    expose:
      - 5432
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=dem
      - POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_EXTENSIONS=postgis,hstore,postgis_topology,postgis_raster,pgrouting
    networks:
      - postgis_net
    volumes:
      - postgis-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        # postgis_logs:/var/lib/postgresql/logs

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin4_container
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin
    networks:
      - postgis_net
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    depends_on:
      - postgis


volumes:
  postgis-data:
  pgadmin-data:

networks:
  postgis_net:
    driver: bridge
```

Everything works perfectly (I can enter the DB postgis in pgadmin4) but I can't seem to connect the docker container with the QGIS application:

[image]

and

[image]

I've been reading all the possible solutions for several days but I can't get over this hurdle. In general, it is my understanding (but I could be wrong) that you have to operate in changing the `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` files. Of course, each proposed solution is different and I tried to apply all of them by building containers from scratch several times.

my `pg_hba.conf` in the docker container (postgis)[`var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf`] is:

```
# PostgreSQL Client Authentication Configuration File
# ===================================================
#
# Refer to the "Client Authentication" section in the PostgreSQL
# documentation for a complete description of this file.  A short
# synopsis follows.
#
# This file controls: which hosts are allowed to connect, how clients
# are authenticated, which PostgreSQL user names they can use, which
# databases they can access.  Records take one of these forms:
#
# local         DATABASE  USER  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# host          DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostssl       DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostnossl     DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostgssenc    DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostnogssenc  DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
#
# (The uppercase items must be replaced by actual values.)
#
# The first field is the connection type:
# - "local" is a Unix-domain socket
# - "host" is a TCP/IP socket (encrypted or not)
# - "hostssl" is a TCP/IP socket that is SSL-encrypted
# - "hostnossl" is a TCP/IP socket that is not SSL-encrypted
# - "hostgssenc" is a TCP/IP socket that is GSSAPI-encrypted
# - "hostnogssenc" is a TCP/IP socket that is not GSSAPI-encrypted
#
# DATABASE can be "all", "sameuser", "samerole", "replication", a
# database name, or a comma-separated list thereof. The "all"
# keyword does not match "replication". Access to replication
# must be enabled in a separate record (see example below).
#
# USER can be "all", a user name, a group name prefixed with "+", or a
# comma-separated list thereof.  In both the DATABASE and USER fields
# you can also write a file name prefixed with "@" to include names
# from a separate file.
#
# ADDRESS specifies the set of hosts the record matches.  It can be a
# host name, or it is made up of an IP address and a CIDR mask that is
# an integer (between 0 and 32 (IPv4) or 128 (IPv6) inclusive) that
# specifies the number of significant bits in the mask.  A host name
# that starts with a dot (.) matches a suffix of the actual host name.
# Alternatively, you can write an IP address and netmask in separate
# columns to specify the set of hosts.  Instead of a CIDR-address, you
# can write "samehost" to match any of the server's own IP addresses,
# or "samenet" to match any address in any subnet that the server is
# directly connected to.
#
# METHOD can be "trust", "reject", "md5", "password", "scram-sha-256",
# "gss", "sspi", "ident", "peer", "pam", "ldap", "radius" or "cert".
# Note that "password" sends passwords in clear text; "md5" or
# "scram-sha-256" are preferred since they send encrypted passwords.
#
# OPTIONS are a set of options for the authentication in the format
# NAME=VALUE.  The available options depend on the different
# authentication methods -- refer to the "Client Authentication"
# section in the documentation for a list of which options are
# available for which authentication methods.
#
# Database and user names containing spaces, commas, quotes and other
# special characters must be quoted.  Quoting one of the keywords
# "all", "sameuser", "samerole" or "replication" makes the name lose
# its special character, and just match a database or username with
# that name.
#
# This file is read on server startup and when the server receives a
# SIGHUP signal.  If you edit the file on a running system, you have to
# SIGHUP the server for the changes to take effect, run "pg_ctl reload",
# or execute "SELECT pg_reload_conf()".
#
# Put your actual configuration here
# ----------------------------------
#
# If you want to allow non-local connections, you need to add more
# "host" records.  In that case you will also need to make PostgreSQL
# listen on a non-local interface via the listen_addresses
# configuration parameter, or via the -i or -h command line switches.

# CAUTION: Configuring the system for local "trust" authentication
# allows any local user to connect as any PostgreSQL user, including
# the database superuser.  If you do not trust all your local users,
# use another authentication method.


# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust

host all all all scram-sha-256
```